# Bash Primitive Types

Tags: bash, types

What are the primitive types in bash scripting?  I feel like this is a simple question, but it has been surprisingly hard to find the answer.  I know there are at least arrays because you can do commands such as

```
for file in *.less
  # code working with file
```

so that makes it appear like *.less is an array.

Also, there are string types, because if I have

```
a=y
b=z
c=$a+$b
echo $c
>> y+z
```

are there any other types besides this?  Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**: After doing further research it also appears that there are associative arrays, which can be declared in the following manner

```
declare -A address
```

which I got from [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html).  Are there any examples of other types?

Answer (score 5):

It's an interesting question, here's what I found:

> bash supports several programming primitives shared by most
>   programming languages. It can perform choices (if then else, case), it
>   can loop (for,while, until) and it has functions (function).
>   http://dasher.wustl.edu/chem478/software/unix-tools/bash.html

Bash variables are untyped.

> Unlike many other programming languages, Bash does not segregate its
>   variables by "type." Essentially, Bash variables are character
>   strings, but, depending on context, Bash permits arithmetic operations
>   and comparisons on variables. The determining factor is whether the
>   value of a variable contains only digits.
>   http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/untyped.html

Bash provides one-dimensional indexed and associative array variables.
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays